# Why JSON doesn't return Lithuanian characters

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have a program that takes strings from MySQL database, creates SqlLite database with same strings and then displays them in Android application ListView.

Problem is that when I get response from PHP side it shows Lithuanian charactes as "?", but I use

> JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE

in json_encode function. Where is the problem?

I want to mention that MySql unicode is set to "utf8_lithuanian_ci"

PHP file :

```
include_once 'db_functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $users = $db->getMarsrutaiCount();
    $a = array();
    $b = array();
    if ($users != false){
        $no_of_users = mysqli_num_rows($users);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users)) {     
            $b["id"] = $row["id"];
            $b["marsrutas"] = $row["marsrutas"];
            $b["pasirinkimas_id"] = $row["pasirinkimas_id"];
            array_push($a,$b);
        }
        echo json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
```

JSON Response from Android side :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersynclist;
        usersynclist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Create GSON object
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        try {
            // Extract JSON array from the response
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
            System.out.println(arr.length());
            // If no of array elements is not zero
            if(arr.length() != 0){
                // Loop through each array element, get JSON object which has userid and username
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    // Get JSON object
                    if(veiksmas == 1) {
                        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
                        System.out.println(obj.get("id"));
                        System.out.println(obj.get("marsrutas"));
                        System.out.println(obj.get("pasirinkimas_id"));
                        // DB QueryValues Object to insert into SQLite
                        queryValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        // Add userID extracted from Object
                        queryValues.put("id", obj.get("id").toString());
                        // Add userName extracted from Object
                        queryValues.put("marsrutas", obj.get("marsrutas").toString());
                        queryValues.put("pasirinkimas_id", obj.get("pasirinkimas_id").toString());
                        // Insert User into SQLite DB
                        controller.insertMarsrutas(queryValues);
```

Comment: Do you see the results ok if you get the json feed from a browser? Also add the code where you get the JSON feed from the server.

Comment: I think the problem is in the encoding. How can I make original unicode to receive? @Juan

Comment: {"id":"1","marsrutas":"Lietavos g. - AB Achema","pasirinkimas_id":"1"},{"id":"2","marsrutas":"Autobus? stotis - Seneli? Pensionatas - Rimkai (galioja nuo 2017-04-05)","pasirinkimas_id":"1"}

Comment: 1 - If you get the json feed from the server with a browser or with postman do you see it ok or not? 2 - If you see it ok the problem is in the app so add to the question the part where you get the feed from from the server.